# Mac OS Sphinx Installation: too few arguments

Tags: python-sphinx

I am currently trying to install Sphinx on Mac OS and while I managed to fix the issue where `sphinx-quickstart could not be found`, now when I want to execute it I get this error:

```
usage: sphinx-quickstart [OPTIONS] <PROJECT_DIR>
sphinx-quickstart: error: too few arguments
```

I'm really not too sure why it wants any arguments as every tutorial and installation instruction showed that this sphinx-quickstart script is just executed as-is to setup the whole thing and thus doesn't need any inputs.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you install Sphinx? Did you install it into a virtual environment (recommended)? Did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: @StevePiercy No. Why should one do that? I installed it via pip.

Comment: Short answer: because it avoids problems like the one you are having now. For a longer and detailed answer, read about it under the authoritative source, the Python Packaging Authority (PyPA) [Installing Packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/). Or search for "why use virtual environment and activate in Python".

Comment: Okay thanks. I’ll do that, then.. Should it work that way or is there anything else that I’ll have to watch out for?

Comment: Hello @StevePiercy I installed virtualenv and setup a virtual environment, in which I installed sphinx. Still not working, and giving me the exact same error message. Pretty weird..

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: Yup. I activated it

Comment: Perhaps the path to your Python is munged. How did you install your Python? What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: It includes this (amongst other stuff that I added): Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem. The solution is as indicated in the error message: you have to specify a project_dir.

If you want to start at the current path, just type:

```
sphinx-quickstart .
```